# How to pass value from input has multi languages using AJAX post request in LARAVEL

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use AJAX post request in my LARAVEL project which must pass multi values from some inputs to the Controller but the problem is that Iam using astrotomic/laravel-translatable for multi Language and i don't know how to pass multi id for same input and how to handle this by AJAX request

My Blade code :

```
<form id="itemForm" class="icons-tab-steps" action="{{ url('/items/store') }}" method="post">
@csrf

@method('PUT')
<!-- Step 1 -->
<h6><i class="step-icon ft-home"></i> @lang('site.basic_data')</h6>
<fieldset>
<div class="row">
    @foreach (config('translatable.locales') as $locale)
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">

            <label>@lang('site.' . $locale . '.title')</label>
            <input type="text" name="{{ $locale }}[title]"
                id="{{ $locale }}[title]"
                class="form-control border-primary"
                value="{{ old($locale . '.title') }}">
        </div><!-- end of group -->
    @endforeach


</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="brand_id">@lang('site.brand')</label>
        <select class="form-control select2 status-type"
            style="width: 100%;" name="brand_id" id="brand">
            <option selected disabled>@lang('site.select_brand')</option>
            @foreach ($brands as $brand)
                <option value="{{ $brand->id }}">{{ $brand->name }}
                </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="version_id">@lang('site.version')</label>
        <select class="form-control select2 status-type"
            style="width: 100%;" name="version_id" id="version">

            {{-- @foreach ($versions as $version)
        <option value="{{ $version->id }}" {{ $version->brand_id == $brand->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $version->name }}</option>
           
        @endforeach --}}
        </select>
    </div>



    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="price_before">@lang('site.price_before')</label>
            <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                <input type="number" id="price_before" class="form-control"
                    name="price_before" placeholder="0"
                    onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                    onblur="findTotal()"
                    value="{{ number_format(old('price_before'), 2) }}">
                <div class="form-control-position">
                    <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my jQuary code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });


        $(".icons-tab-steps").steps({
            headerTag: "h6",
            bodyTag: "fieldset",
            transitionEffect: "fade",
            titleTemplate: '<span class="step">#index#</span> #title#',
            labels: {
                finish: "Submit",
            },
            onFinished: function(e, currentIndex) {

                const car = [{
            // "title": $({{ $locale }}[title]).val(),
           
            _token: $("input#token").val(),
            _method: "POST",
            "brand": $("input#brand").val(),
            "version": $("input#version").val(),
            "price_before": $("input#price_before").val(),
            "price_after": $("input#price_after").val()
        }];

        var form = $('form#itemForm');
                e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the page from refreshing

                $(this).html("Sending..");
                jQuery.ajax({
                   
                    url: "{{ route('items.store') }}",
                   
                    data: car,
                    type: "POST",
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                   
                    success: function(data) {
                        
                        $("#itemForm").trigger("reset");
                        $("#icon-tabs").modal("hide");
                        table.draw();
                    },

                    error: function(data) {
                        if (data.status === 422) {
                            var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                            $.each(errors, function(key, value) {
                                // console.log(key+ " " +value);
                                $('#response').addClass("alert alert-danger");

                                if ($.isPlainObject(value)) {
                                    $.each(value, function(key, value) {
                                        console.log(key + " " + value);
                                        $('#response').show().append(
                                            value + "<br/>");

                                    });
                                } else {
                                    $('#response').show().append(value +
                                        "<br/>"); //this is my div with messages
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                });
            },
         });
```

my controller code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $rules = [

        'main_cover' => 'required',
        'cover' => 'required',
        'price_before' => 'required',
        'price_now' => 'required',
        'price_after' => 'required',
        'price_offer' => 'required',
        'upon_request' => 'required',
        'in_stock' => 'required',
     
    ];

    foreach (config('translatable.locales') as $locale) {
        $rules += [$locale . '.title' => ['required', Rule::unique('item_translations', 'title')]];
        $rules += [$locale . '.engine' => 'required'];
        $rules += [$locale . '.luxury' => 'required'];
        $rules += [$locale . '.safety' => 'required'];
        $rules += [$locale . '.extra' => 'required'];
    }
    $rules += [
        'brand_id' => 'required',
      
    ];
    $request->validate($rules);

    $request_data = $request->all();
    if ($request_data)
    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'msg' => 'تم الحفظ بنجاح',
    ]);
```

i tried to pass values as parameters but don't know how to pass input with multi language value.